# how to turn a function to wait for REST resquests

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I want to get an array of keys from JIRA. The current function is working but when I call the variable pendingIssues at the end of the program, it's empty as the request are not yet treated by the function get_all_issues.

How can I change the function to wait the requests from the function before asking for pendingIssues.

the code :

```js
var pendingIssues = [];

function get_all_issues() {

  console.log("Getting all JIRA issues...");

  var TotalIssues = 1000;
  var count_issue;
  var flag_no_more_issue = 0;


  for (count_issue = 0; count_issue < TotalIssues; count_issue+=50){

    console.log(count_issue);

    //envoi de la requête
    jira.searchJira(searchString = 'project= PITM',
    optional ={
      startAt:count_issue,
      maxResults:50,
      fields:["key"],
      }).then(function(issues) {

      //Ensemble des tickets à traiter
      console.log('--------------------------- ');
      console.log(Date.now());
      var pas;
      for (pas = 0; pas < 50 && flag_no_more_issue != 1 ; pas++){
        if (issues.issues[0] != null){
          pendingIssues.push(issues.issues.pop().key)
          console.log(pendingIssues.length)
          //console.log(pas);
        }
        else{
          var flag_no_more_issue = 1;
          console.log('no more issue !')
        }
      }
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
      });
    }
  }


get_all_issues()
console.log('-----------------------------')
console.log(pendingIssues)
```

Comment: Are you a python programmer? That's not the way we pass parameters in js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the asynchronous code you execute.
You need to move your `console.log(pendingIssues)` into your `then` section (when your Promise is effectively resolved).

Or better, you can make of your `get_all_issues` function a Promise, like this:

```
function get_all_issues() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     // your JIRA request etc
     ...
     .then(function(issues){
       resolve(issues)
     })
     .catch(function(err){
       reject(err)
     })
  })
}
```

And then use your Promise like this:

```
get_all_issues.then(function(pendingIssues){
  console.log(pendingIssues)
})
```

You ccan find infos about `Promise` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Promise

Answer (score 0):

Collect all the requests in an array an then you can use Promise.all(requestArray).then(...) to do some logic after all the promises are resolved.

It could look like this:

```
for (count_issue = 0; count_issue < TotalIssues; count_issue+=50){
  pendingIssues.push(
    jira.searchJira(
      'project= PITM',
      {
        startAt:count_issue,
        maxResults:50,
        fields:["key"],
      }).then(function(issues) {

        //Ensemble des tickets à traiter
        console.log('--------------------------- ');
        console.log(Date.now());
        var pas;
        for (pas = 0; pas < 50 && flag_no_more_issue != 1 ; pas++){
          if (issues.issues[0] != null){
            pendingIssues.push(issues.issues.pop().key)
            console.log(pendingIssues.length)
            //console.log(pas);
          }
          else{
            var flag_no_more_issue = 1;
            console.log('no more issue !')
          }
        }
      }).catch(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
      });
    }
  )
}

Promise.all(pendingIssues).then(res => console.log(res))
```